# is there a way to download multiple files using the requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to download multiple .hdr files from a website called hdrihaven.com.
My knowledge of python is not that great but here is what I have tried so far:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://hdrihaven.com/files/hdris/'
resolution = '4k'
file = 'pump_station' #would need to be every file

url_2k = url + file + '_' + resolution + '.hdr'
print(url_2k)

r = requests.get(url_2k, allow_redirects=True)
open(file + resolution + '.hdr', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Idealy `file` would just loop over every file in the directory.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

**EDIT**

I found a script on github that does what I need: https://github.com/Alzy/hdrihaven_dl. I edited it to fit my needs here: https://github.com/ktkk/hdrihaven-downloader. It uses the technique of looping through a list of all available files as proposed in the comments.

I have found that the requests module as well as urllib are extremly slow compared to native downloading from eg. Chrome. If anyone has an idea as to how I can speed these up pls let me know.

Comment: Get the list of files from the corresponding url, by parsing the returned contents, then loop over that list and retrieve every file individually.

Comment: then when you're feeling crazy, add multiprocessing to do it in parallel

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do this:

1. You can use an `URL`to fetch all the files and iterate through a loop to download them individually. This of course only works if there exists such a `URL`.
2. You can pass in individual `URL` to a function that can download them in parallel/bulk.

For example:

```
import os
import requests
from time import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def url_response(url):
    path, url = url
    r = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for ch in r:
            f.write(ch)

urls = [("Event1", "https://www.python.org/events/python-events/805/"),("Event2", "https://www.python.org/events/python-events/801/"),
("Event3", "https://www.python.org/events/python-user-group/816/")]


start = time()

for x in urls:
    url_response (x)
print(f"Time to download: {time() - start}")
```

This code snippet is taken from here [Download multiple files (Parallel/bulk download)](https://likegeeks.com/downloading-files-using-python/). Read on there for more information on how you can do this.